# Embedded Google Map Code not showing for IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to embedded google map code. It is designed to use geolocation and show traffic around your area live. It works in Chrome and Firefox. But does not with IE. It wont even show an error message. Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you.

Here is the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">     </script>
<article>

</article>
<script>
function success(position) {
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '350px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';

  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

var options = {
zoom: 12,
center: coords,
mapTypeControl: false,
navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coords,
  map: map,

});
var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);


}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
error('Geo Location is not supported');
}

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: quick comment where is your [g-map api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) ?

Comment: Dont have one. Does that matter?

Comment: yes i think so , it is use to limit API hits.

Comment: Also, do you initialize the map?  Are you following the example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)?  When I did this I copied it almost to the letter.